# How to find a cell where a value is different than something (Excel)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an excel file with a column filled with 'o's. 
However there must be a row in that colum where a cell is not filled with a 'o' (is empty)

Manually looking for the cell, is fruitless. There are so many that I just can not find it.

How can I make a formula that permits me to:

find the cell (from all the cells ina column) where the value is different than 'o' (is empty)?

Comment: Kansai ,, if I suggest Conditional formatting which highlight all empty Cells in the Column,  will this works for you ?

Comment: Well, yeah I can try :) Conditional formatting you say.. I ll look into that

Comment: Wow, there must be something really wrong with this excel sheet. I tried conditional formatting and could not find the empty space :(

Comment: did you try the way I've accomplished it? And one more are those blank cells have any Formula ?

Comment: Thanks. I ll try it when I am back at the office :)

Comment: Conditional formatting is a good choose.

Comment: Do you need a formula? An alternative is to simply use a Filter, and you can either filter out the empty spaces, or filter out the `o` cells.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

**How it works:**

- Select the required data Range or Entire Column.
- From Home TAB select `Conditional Formatting`.
- Click, `New Rule` then from `Select Rule Type`.
- Click, `Use Formula which Cells to format`.
- Below you find `Edit the Rule description`.
- Write this Formula in Text Box `=ISBLANK($A1)`.
- Hit `Format Button` & apply an appropriate 
  Format and finish with `Ok`.

*As soon you finish with all I've shown Excel will highlight blank Cells.*

Answer (score 0):

Click on the header of that column containing 'o's, click Menu - Data - Filter.

Now, click on downarrow icon that appears at the end of header name.

it will open a list of all values in that field. 
Untick select All
Tick on Text filters, select Does Not equal, in the next window, enter o

This will hide all values that are o, and shall show only those value that are Empty or are anything other than o.